# Modelling calculated fields in Rest API

Tags: performance, rest, api-design

It is a common practice for Restful resources to support field selectors in the query string. For example, if a resource has fields A,B,C and D but the client is interested only in a subset of fields (say A and B) then the Url might look like

> .../resource/1/?fields=A,B // only A and B are 'selected'

Now supposed we add another property to the resource. The thing with this property is that it does not have any physical storage. It is a computed value. Also suppose that this *computation is very expensive*.

Now obviously, Rest does not care about such things, whether data comes from a file a DB or a fancy algorithm.

But here comes a dilemma: the 'fields' query parameter is always optional. In my case, omitting 'fields' means "bring all the fields" (much like '*' in SQL):

> .../resource/1 // A,B,C,D and E(xpensive) are 'selected'

I am positive that there are many existing clients that are  using the naive approach (not bothering to specify an explicit list of fields). This means that adding this new heavy property will unintentionally create a performance break (possibly a very severe one).

What are the common techniques to cope with these situations?

Alternatives I considered:

1. Add a special notion to the system that says that querying with '*' semantics will not necessarily return ALL the fields (heavy fields will be omitted by default). If a client wants them- he must ask for them *explicitly*
2. Not to model these extra properties as fields on the resource. Instead expose a dedicated endpoint that will carry out the computation, thus eliminating possible confusion but introducing Rest-RPC style into the system.
3. Make it the cilent's problem: if he did not bother to be explicit in the first place, tough for him. That is not really an option- don't have this privilege.

Comment: I like 1 best. I'd consider representing these fields as referenced object, and then you could get to them HATEOAS style, through separate calls for the heavy fields. This is similar to how web-pages behave -- return the framework and some content, then force extra calls if the user wants the images, videos, etc.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, that is an interesting approach. Can you direct me to articles/book chapters that elaborate on it? Also- are you aware of any "famous" existing rest APIs that implement this approach? (I already looked at facebook and linkedin, no luck there).

Comment: Yeah, take a look at this: http://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS, this: http://timelessrepo.com/haters-gonna-hateoas, and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hateoas

Comment: @EngineerDollery, you are welcome to post comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like option 1 best. I'd consider representing these fields as referenced object, and then you could get to them HATEOAS style, through separate calls for the heavy fields. This is similar to how web-pages behave -- return the framework and some content, then force extra calls if the user wants the images, videos, etc. –

Take a look at this: spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS, this: timelessrepo.com/haters-gonna-hateoas, and this: stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hateoas